Is there any VSCode API that lets me know the actual physical line in the viewport the cursor is on?
In the VS Code API you can get the line number the cursor is on from vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.active. The line returned is the logical line that counts the number of new lines that show up before the cursor.
Now I want to have the number of lines shown on the display before the cursor position. That may be different then the value above if I have code folding or line wrapping.
Is there any API function that returns such value?
I tried to find something in the VS Code documentation available online, but failed to find the info I want.

If you mean something like the viewport height or visible top line and visible bottom line  I don't think there is anyway to get that info.  There are reveal commands to show things that may not be visible in the viewport.

I think the only thing you can work with is
const visibleRanges = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.visibleRanges;

It returns an array.  Folded regions are in their own array members, like visibleRanges[1], visibleRanges[2], etc.
So you could figure out the number of visible lines by doing the math on all the ranges, subtracting the Range.end.line from Range.start.line over all the array members and adding them up until your cursor position.
It is easier to see which lines are shown then how many lines are shown, but you can get both from vscode.window.activeTextEditor.visibleRanges.
